# xargs can't handle spaces in lines

Tags: bash, xargs

All the target files have been deleted. Of course, when I try to run any deletes again, the files aren't there to delete. Sorry to take your time.

---

I'm using bash on cygwin.

I have the output of `fdupes` in a file. I'm grepping the output to exclude a directory I want to keep intact, and wanting to delete the rest of the files listed.

I have some entries with spaces:

`./NewVolume/keep/2009/conference/conference/conference 004.jpg`

Which trips up `xargs`:

```
$ cat real-dupes.txt |xargs rm {}
...
rm: cannot remove ‘2009/conference/conference/conference’: No such file or directory`
```

When I try the `-0` switch, it looks like the lines get globbed together:

```
$ cat real-dupes.txt |xargs -0 rm
xargs: argument line too long
```

Other questions have answers where the asker is adviced to use `find` to feed the arguments into `xargs`. That's not helpful in my scenario, because I don't believe that I can easily use `find` to identify the duplicates I want to get rid of. Also, the fdupes job ran some 12+ hours, so I really want to use this data set.

As far as I know, `fdupes` cannot exclude a directory from its automated delete, so I can't use it out of the box, either.

Comment: If it's *just* spaces you should be able to handle it with: `sed 's/ /\\ /' real-dupes.txt | xargs rm {}`.  This won't handle the many other special characters that can be present in filenames, though; for some examples: `*$<tab>"'`  See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) for more details.

Comment: @Wildcard I got the same errors with your sed solution: `rm: cannot remove ‘2009/photos’: No such file or directory` -- there may be other characters that are problematic, but the majority of the errors thrown are from this apparent space. Pretty sure I used the normal space bar to name these files, although some originated on NTFS filesystems.

Comment: I mis-diagnosed the problem I was experiencing and all the answers are superfluous.

Comment: So, what, the `sed` solution deleted the files that remained and had spaces in them?

Comment: That could be, but I tried a number of things with the same error set (Can't delete files), so I'm not sure which one was the first to get it right.

Answer (score 5):

`xargs -0` is not working because it expects a null-terminated string, which it does not find, therefore reading up all the input and globbing its argument.

Just convert every new line (I suppose there is a filename per line) with a `\0`, like this:

```
cat real-dupes.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm {}
```

Comment: :S getting this: `rm: cannot remove ‘./win7/Documents/keep/2009_movies/zoo 010.avi’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: And there is such file in the directory? =)

Comment: ... no ... they've apparently been deleted by previous attempts :P

Answer (score 4):

By default `xargs` splits at whitespace. You may be able to use the [non-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) `-0` [option](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) to split at character `\000`, but your input has to be prepared to match the expectation. (`find ... -print0` is one of the ways of doing this - assuming your version of `find` has the `-print0` option.)

Provided that none of your files contains a new line in their name (i.e. you have one file per line) you can use `xargs` like this:

```
xargs -I{} rm {} <real-dupes.txt
```

The man page for `xargs` has this to say about the `-I` flag:

> **`-I replace-str`**
>                Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with
>                names  read  from  standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
>                terminate input items; instead  the  separator  is  the  newline
>                character.  Implies `-x` and `-L 1`.

Comment: The `-0` option to `xargs` is a [non-standard extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html), as is the `-print0` extension to [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle the OP had first suggested `-0` so it seemed reasonable to reference it in my answer.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable, and quite appropriate, but I think for completeness it's also important to note non-standard extensions so someone who runs across your answer in the future doesn't wonder what's wrong with their version `xargs`.